# Can not get [HttpPost] response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

just started to learn the ASP MVC, I'm trying to make this form where you give your name and email and .... and when you click on **submit** Form, it should lead to the "Thanks" page where you see a thanks message and your name.
but after clicking on "Submit" Button nothing happened for me. I want to know what is the problem.
this is the Homecontroller for all action methods

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PartyInvites.Models;

  namespace PartyInvites.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        int hours = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        ViewBag.Greeting = hours < 12 ? "Good Morning" : "Good Evening";
        return View("MyView") ;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
    {
        Repository.AddResponse(guestResponse);

        return View("Thanks",guestResponse);
    }

}

}
```

this is **"MyView"** page , which is the default page

```
@{
Layout = null;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Greeting World (from the view)
        <p>
            We are going to have an exciting party.<br />
            (to do:sell it better.Add pictures or something.)
        </p>
        <a asp-action="RsvpForm"> Ravp Now</a>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
}
```

this is the **Form page** which you can go there after clicking on **Ravp Now**

```
*@
 @model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

 @{ Layout = null;
  }
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewpot" content="width=device-width"/>
<title>RsvpForm</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post"></form>
 <p>
<label asp-for="Name"> Your Name: </label>
<input asp-for="Name"/>
</p>
<p>
<label asp-for="Email"> Your Email:</label>
<input asp-for="Email"/>
</p>
<p>
<label asp-for="Phone"> Your Phone:</label>
<input asp-for="Phone"/>
</p>
<p>
<label> Will You Attend?</label>
<select asp-for="WillAttend">
    <option value=""> Choose an option </option>
    <option value="true"> Yes, I'll be There. </option>
    <option value="false"> No, i can't come. </option>
</select>
</p>
<button type="submit"> Submit Rsvp</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is here when I click on **Submit Rsvp** , Nothing happens.it won't go to the "Thanks" page. I checked all codes a few times but couldn't find anything.
What could be wrong?
these are the **"Thanks"** View Page and **"Repository"** class model

```
@model GuestResponse
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<title>Thanks</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<h1> Thank you! @Model.Name!</h1>
@if (Model.WillAttend == true)
{
    @:Its great that you're coming.The drinks are already in the Fridge!
}
else
{
@:sorry to here that you can't make it , but thanks for letting us know.
}
</p>
<p> click<a asp-action="ListResponses"> here </a> to see who is coming.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace PartyInvites.Models
 {
 public static class Repository
 {
    private static List<GuestResponse> responses=new List<GuestResponse>();

    public static IEnumerable<GuestResponse> Responses
    {
        get { return responses; }
    }

    public static void AddResponse(GuestResponse response)
    {
        responses.Add(response);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is inside your cshtml file.

All contents of a form must be within such form declaration. I don't have a C# project available to check it right now, but I think the "fixed" code would be something like this:

```
*@
 @model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

 @{ Layout = null;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewpot" content="width=device-width"/>
        <title>RsvpForm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post">
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Name"> Your Name: </label>
                <input asp-for="Name"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Email"> Your Email:</label>
                <input asp-for="Email"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label asp-for="Phone"> Your Phone:</label>
                <input asp-for="Phone"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label> Will You Attend?</label>
                <select asp-for="WillAttend">
                    <option value=""> Choose an option </option>
                    <option value="true"> Yes, I'll be There. </option>
                    <option value="false"> No, i can't come. </option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <button type="submit"> Submit Rsvp</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked , can you tell me exactly what did you changed? Thanks

Comment: My apologies! I forgot to add comments to the code.

In that file, you had this:

` <form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post"></form>`

This creates an empty form, which is closed in the same line, and what you did is adding the form elements and submit buttom after that "form close". You must include all fields and buttons within the form element, as this:

<form  asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post">
<!-- Fields, buttons, ... here -->

</form>

I just removed the "</form>" closing tag from your form declaration around line 12, and moved that closing tag after the submit button.